# Can't target Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, iframe, if-statement

I am trying to make it so that if the browser is Internet Explorer I want to show an iframe, but it isn't working, If I use IE it doesn't show and I can't figure out why.

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Fastlane Autosales</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>


<style>
 body {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden, margin:0}
 html {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden}
  #size {   width: 900px;   
        height: 700px; 
        display: block;}
</style>


 <body>

<!--[if IE]>


<div style="position: absolute; top: 110px; left: 20px;">
<iframe id = "size" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"      style="background-color:#E6E6E6" src="http://listings2011.boostmotorgroup.com/Search.aspx?    DealershipID=4075&amp;isLogo=0&amp;MediaID=36"></iframe>
</div>

<![endif]-->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which IE version (and rendering mode if you have modified it) do you use for displaying?

Comment: What version of IE are you testing with?

Comment: Which IE version, and why would you want to apply special code for it?

Comment: 10 but I want this to happen on all versions

Comment: @CamConnor Conditional Comments have been removed in IE10

Comment: so there is no way to target IE 10?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should remove the whitespace in the URL you're sending to the iFrame.

Comment: @CamConnor there is no way with conditional comments, JavaScript is the only (and always has been the correct) way.

Comment: @JasonSperske do you know any examples i could go to?

Comment: Why do you need to target IE specifically in the first place?

Comment: For a website I am making in google chrome an image is half the page then in IE it is like twice the size, I used the above example just to simplify the question, but I want to make the image smaller in IE

Comment: Maybe you should ask about the *actual* problem. It's probable that there's a solution that doesn't involve targeting IE specifically.

Comment: @Juhana Here is my actual problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088143/internet-explorer-is-re-sizing-my-iframe

Answer (score 3):

Browser detection is brittle and problematic at best.  A cleaner approach would be to do feature detection (test for things you need and enable (or disable) features based on those features.  [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/) is a great way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx), "As of Internet Explorer 10, conditional comments are no longer supported by standards mode".

I verified this by testing your code in IE.  When I switched to browser modes 7-9, I was able to see the iframe, but not in IE 10 mode.