# Internet Explorer is re-sizing my iframe

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have an iframe that fits in the page on google chrome but when I open it in IE10 it is as if the entire page has been zoomed in

Here is an example of chrome

[image]

and here is explorer

[image]

below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Fastlane Autosales</title>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<style>
body {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden, margin:0}
html {width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden}
#size {width: 900px; height: 800px; display: block;}
</style>
 <body>
<div id="wrapper1">
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="menu" class="container">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Homepage</a></li>
            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="inventory.html">Inventory</a></li>
            <li><a href="Finance.html">Financing</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 20px; margin-top: -360px">
<iframe id = "size" frameborder="0" scrolling="yes" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" style="background-color:#E6E6E6" src="http://listings2011.boostmotorgroup.com/Search.aspx?DealershipID=4075&amp;isLogo=0&amp;MediaID=36"></iframe>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: A quick search led me to this article, which (in the 2nd solution) suggests using a `meta` tag for IE10: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/594501/InplusIE10-2cplusIframeplusdoesplusnotplusadjustpl

Comment: If you set the value of the meta tag mentioned above to IE=edge, the browser will default to the latest supported version instead of compatibility mode.